# how to do truncation of text in UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel, line-breaks

I have problem with truncation of text in `UILabel` even I have set `lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` perfectly.

Here is my code snippet :

```
lblSelectedText = [[UILabel alloc] init];
lblSelectedText.numberOfLines = 0;
lblSelectedText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
lblSelectedText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Regular" size:(IS_IPAD_PRO?13.0:9.0)];
lblSelectedText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
lblSelectedText.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
lblSelectedText.text = strKey; // Here text will be dynamic

CGFloat width = 150;
CGSize strSize = [self findHeightForText:strKey havingWidth:width andFont:lblSelectedText.font];
lblSelectedText.frame = CGRectMake(12, 10, CGRectGetWidth(aContainerController.view.frame)-20, strSize.height+15);


- (CGSize)findHeightForText:(NSString *)text havingWidth:(CGFloat)widthValue andFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
    if (text)
    {
        if (IS_ENGLISH) {
            CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil];
            size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height + 10);
        }
        else {
            CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil];
            size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height + 1);
        }
    }
    return size;
}
```

Please note that these labels are in collection view cell. Here are some reference images.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

If anyone have solution of this problem please share with me...

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly do you want?

Comment: do you want to show ellipsis not complete text?

Comment: Not getting what you are asking!! Do you want label which is truncate if text(string) is long enough ?

Comment: I have enough width and dynamic height of label...and I want to fit my text in that label. For that I have set require properties `lineBreakMode` and `numberOfLines`, then also its not working as you can see in image...words are not wrapping up... In "Government" "t" goes in next line...and in "Dependents" "s" is in next line...

Comment: what's the desired behavior? "t" and "s" should stay in the first line? or should appear some "..."?

Comment: "t and "s" should be stayed in first line

Comment: @VRAwesome : for that you have to increase label width or reduce fontsize otherwise it is not possible. check my answer if it can help!

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in comment that some characters goes in to next line that means there is not enough width to fill every letter in single line thats why it is going to second line as you set number of line to 0(i.e. multiple lines). So there is nothing is wrong in it. It is normal behavior according to your setup made in code.

now if you want that it not goes to second line then set `numberOfLines` property to `1`.

Another option is you can set `minimunScaleFactor` from `0 to 1` to resize your font to fit in available width.

You can do it something like,

```
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5f;
```

So, It will reduce font size to half of the actual to fit it in availabel width.

And once try by changing `linebreakmode` to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` also instead of `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`.

Comment: I cannot set `numberOfLines = 1`, if I set it then how text display when it contains more words(i.e. more than 1 or 2)...

Comment: Let me try another solution.. :)

Comment: And once try `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` linebreakmode also!

Comment: And yes, above solution `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5f;` not worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Check this:-

label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5f;

label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;

[label sizeToFit];